# Cake php: Error Table cates for model Cate was not found in datasource default

Tags: php, cakephp

When i run the `./cake bake all` command i get the following error:

[image: my sql in connection stat]
Running with xampp  -

[image: how to fix this problem ?]

Answer (score 0):

Cake expects there to be a table that corresponds to every Model class.  The standard format for the table names is the pluralized version of the model name. It is failing because you don't have a table `cates`, which is the plural form of your model `Cate`.

You can get around this by specifying what table you want the model to use by setting [$useTable](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#usetable) in the model.

Cate Model:

```
$useTable = 'categories'
```

Comment: your mean difference between uppercase and lowercase name table ?

Comment: I am using cakephp 2.5.5 console

Comment: table names should be lowercase, but I don't think that's your issue.  its looking for a table that doesn't exist.  you need to either rename the table or set the `$useTable` property in the model.